# most common 2-grams using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark, n-gram, python-collections

Given a string:

```
this is a test this is
```

How can I find the top-n most common 2-grams? In the string above, all 2-grams are:

```
{this is, is a, test this, this is}
```

As you can notice, the 2-gram `this is` appears 2 times. Hence the result should be:

```
{this is: 2}
```

I know I can use `Counter.most_common()` method to find the most common elements, but how can I create a list of 2-grams from the string to begin with?

Comment: Show us some code!

Comment: Pardon my OCD, but shouldn't "a test" also be a 2-gram? It doesn't appear in the list

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the method provided in this [blog post](http://locallyoptimal.com/blog/2013/01/20/elegant-n-gram-generation-in-python/) to conveniently create n-grams in Python.

```
from collections import Counter

bigrams = zip(words, words[1:])
counts = Counter(bigrams)
print(counts.most_common())
```

That assumes that the input is a list of words, of course. If your input is a string like the one you provided (which does not have any punctuation), then you can do just `words = text.split(' ')` to get a list of words. In general, though, you would have to take punctuation, whitespace and other non-alphabetic characters into account. In that case you might do something like

```
import re

words = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+', text)
```

or you could use an external library such as [nltk.tokenize](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html).

Edit. If you need tri-grams or any other any other n-grams in general then you can use the function provided in the blog post I linked to:

```
def find_ngrams(input_list, n):
  return zip(*(input_list[i:] for i in range(n)))

trigrams = find_ngrams(words, 3)
```

Comment: now, if I need to do tri-grams instead of bigrams, how can I do that - just curious.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use

```
words = s.split() # s is the original string
pairs = [(words[i], words[i+1]) for i in range(len(words)-1)]
```

`(words[i], words[i+1])` is the pair of words at place i and i+1, and we go over all pairs from (0,1) to (n-2, n-1) with n being the length of the string s.

Comment: `s` is a string, think you mean `s.split()`. Also you haven't counted anything yet...

Comment: @Chris_Rands `s` is never used in OP's question, so it might just as well be a list of words. But this should certainly be made clear in the answer.

Comment: @Chris_Rands, you are, of course, correct. I have modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is:

```py
s = "this is a test this is"
words = s.split()
words_zip = zip(words, words[1:])
two_grams_list = [item for item in words_zip]
print(two_grams_list)
```

Above code will give you list of all two-grams like:

```
[('this', 'is'), ('is', 'a'), ('a', 'test'), ('test', 'this'), ('this', 'is')]
```

Now, we need to count the frequency of each two-grams

```py
count_freq = {}
for item in two_grams_list:
    if item in count_freq:
        count_freq[item] +=1
    else:
        count_freq[item] = 1
```

Now, we need to sort the result in descending order and print the result.

```py
sorted_two_grams = sorted(count_freq.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse = True)
print(sorted_two_grams)
```

output:

```
[(('this', 'is'), 2), (('is', 'a'), 1), (('a', 'test'), 1), (('test', 'this'), 1)]
```